# How to insert smooth table in R markdown presentations slidy, ioslides or beamer

Tags: r-markdown, slidy

I am preparing an R markdown presentation, but I couldn't find how to arrange table view. For example all numbers are left alligned.

Is there an easy way to arrange R markdown tables? 
And could anyone suggest an advanced resource on R markdown presentations?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Look for `knitr::kable` or the [`pander` package](http://rapporter.github.io/pander/#markdown-tables)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I find the [resources on the Rmarkdown website](http://rmarkdown.rstudio.com/authoring_pandoc_markdown.html) to be quite good. The example below shows how to do alignment of simple tables.

```
 Right      Left     Center     Default
-------     ------ ----------   -------
     12     12        12            12
    123     123       123          123
      1     1          1             1

Table:  Demonstration of simple table syntax.
```

> The headers and table rows must each fit on one line. Column alignments are determined by the position of the header text relative to the dashed line below it:
>
> If the dashed line is flush with the header text on the right side but extends beyond it on the left, the column is right-aligned.
>   If the dashed line is flush with the header text on the left side but extends beyond it on the right, the column is left-aligned.
>   If the dashed line extends beyond the header text on both sides, the column is centered.
>   If the dashed line is flush with the header text on both sides, the default alignment is used (in most cases, this will be left).